# How to highlight image after selection of image using css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
img {
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 22px 1px #333;
}
.image-rounded {
border-radius: 6px;
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
}

.well {
width: 100%;
}

.scroll {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.scroll a {
display: inline-block;
width: 140px;
margin: 10px;
}

.scroll a img {
width: 100%;
}

.scroll a:focus {
border: 1px solid yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="well">
  <div class="scroll">
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
  </div>
</div>
```

I have multiple images in a page that is select-able by user. User can select any image by simply click on that image. How can i highlight that image after selection.so how can i highlight selected image using `css` or `jquery`

I am getting a yellow outline when i am clicking on the image. And on click image should be shown selected with a shadow till i shift to next image.

Comment: I don't understand the issue

Comment: your code already does that, check to it . have created the script and just added the bg color to highlight it

Comment: here it is doing in my html full page it is not doing

Comment: Can you show your html page. Have you added the jquery lib ?

Comment: These are the 2 jquery lib i added.   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: do you get any console errors ? have you checked your browser console ? I strongly believe that if you debug your code in browser, you will find the solution for your code

Comment: Okay i am doing it. Any another better solution

Comment: Are you defining  your click handler inside `$(document).ready(...)` ???

Comment: Remove one of the jquery links. You don't need both of them. Show us the console errors and the full html page or we can't help you. Also use `$(document).ready(function{});`

Comment: okay i removed it.And  added it too.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your snippet @@

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass('className')` function to highlight the selected images. Below is the working version.

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  //New Code replaced here
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
img {
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 22px 1px #333;
}
.image-rounded {
border-radius: 6px;
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
}

.well {
width: 100%;
}

.scroll {
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.scroll a {
display: inline-block;
width: 140px;
margin: 10px;
}

.scroll a img {
width: 100%;
}

.scroll a:focus {
border: 1px solid yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="well">
  <div class="scroll">
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
    <img src='https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-shadow-social/48/twitter-128.png' />
  </div>
</div>
```